# How to specify the created PDF version in MikTeX?

Tags: pdftex, miktex2.9

I use `MiKTeX 22.3` out of the box; I don't think changed the default configuration in any way. If it is relevant, I use it with Texniccenter.

I am trying to use the command `\includegraphics{myfile}` with `\usepackage{epstopdf}` before it, where myfile.eps is an EPS file located in the directory indicated in `\graphicpath`.

The system is able to find the file and correctly creates `myfile-eps-converted-to.pdf`.

However then an error appears:

> o.pdf): PDF inclusion: found PDF version <1.7>, but at most version <1.5> allowed

and no picture appears in the created pdf file.

Surprisingly, the converted-to file is created by MiTeX itself out of the box. Then it looks like a bug in the MiKTeX installation, which produces incompatible pdf versions.

I have googled around a lot and some folks recommend fiddling with some configuration files tricky to find, and even if I find the recommended file, I don't understand its format.

Is there any well-documented way to allow MiKTeX's `pdflatex` to cope with the pdf version 1.7? I assume that there is no way to tell MiKTeX's `epstopdf` to produce version 1.5, or is there? Ideally, I expected the official way to be available through Miktex's own configuration console, is it? And how?

I need to send my project to the publisher. If they use MiKTeX, they will not be ale to compile my project. But even if I solve the problem locally by fiddling with my local configuration, is there any way to provide this fix with some file in the source directory along with my .tex file (or in the TeX file itself?) for the problem not to reappear at the receiving end? I think I have seen a TeX command somewhere to place in the TeX file, something like `\pdfversion` (but not exactly this ). Is there such a command to specify the allowed pdf version in the tex file itself?

Hint: I saw these commands:

```
\pdfminorversion=5
\pdfobjcompresslevel=5
```

Can this be used to solve my problem? How?

Even if I **can** do it, a better question is whether I **should** fiddle with the pdf version in the tex file, ot the publisher has their own preset configuration ccording to their rules, and with these command in the tex file I will only break it and they will cancel my paper since it will break their pipeline?

Comment: You use relative old MiKTeX version. Recent version is 23.5. Try to update it. Using it and compiled by `pdfLaTeX` you not need to load `epstopdf` package (anymore). Result of compilation  by `pdfLaTeX` is pdf file version 1.5.

Comment: I added"\pdfminorversion=7" to the .tex  file. Now the output file is produced with version 1.7, but  the pictures still are not shown in the produced PDF, even though the error message about allowed pdf version seems to have gone away. So now it is **worse**: the pictures are ignored with no error message at all. Any idea ? What can I try?

Comment: The inclusion warning is only a warning and wouldn't prevent the graphic to appear. Something else is wrong. Check the converted pdf.

Comment: I opened an issue regarding the pdfversion https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/1354. But as I wrote this is not the source of your problem with the missing graphics.